# Can I create a single VM in GCP with my own Windows Server 2019 licence key?

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, windows-server

Is it possible to create a single VM (2 cpu) in Google Cloud Platform with an existing Windows Server 2019 licence key?

When I follow this guide below to create sole-tenant VMs in GCP it seems the only node types in the node templates have huge amounts of CPUs? Such as n1-node-96-624 (96CPU) and c2-node-60-240 (60 CPU) etc.

When I spin any of the options up it hits my account CPU limit. I just want a small VM with my own activation key to reduce costs.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/provisioning-sole-tenant-vms

Comment: Microsoft and Google require specific licensing:  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/ms-licensing AND https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/ms-licensing-faq

Answer (score 1):

There is 2 parts in your question:

- Can you use your own licence on GCP? Yes and No.

  - No because Microsoft licence terms forbid this, except is you use Azure (of course).
  - Yes, you technically can, but if Microsoft performs a controls on your platform, you can have penalties!
- Sole tenant is the reservation of a physical server, only or you. If you don't want to share the hardware infrastructure with others. And thus, you can only reserve a full server: 60 or 96 cpu, not less.